# MQ - 2142 error

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq

I am new to Java-MQ programming. I am facing a strange issue.

I am trying to send a text message to WMQ V7 using java.

In my code I have a property called identifier which I am setting to the message by using the method `msg.setStringProperty("IDENTIFIER", "XXXXX");`

I deployed the code in Unix system and while testing I am getting `MQ-2142` error MQRC_HEADER_ERROR.

The strange thing is when I am running the same code from my local desktop using netbeans-6.9 (like a standalone application) it is executing successfully.

Please help me out with this issue?

Comment: Can you let us know the exact MQ version you are using? I am aware of some APAR fixes which may apply. For example, http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV27345

Are you using message grouping?

It may also be helpful for troubleshooting if you can copy/paste the RFH2 structure of your message header.